# How can I create an array of matrices in/with/for alglib

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, linear-algebra, alglib

I'm trying to make an array of 2d matrices to calculate the eigenvalues with the Alglib library in C++, but I can't find how I can make an array of matrices (if this is possible) to calculate their eigenvalues. I know how to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvector for 1 matrix, but for several of them, at the same time, I don't know. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What language would you like to use? C#? Python? Please edit your question and add the corresponding language tag. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice.

Comment: You are welcome, but I meant to add it as a *tag*. See that right now, below your question, you have "arrays", "matrix", "linear-algebra" and "alglib"? You should add C++ *there*. This way your question will also become more visible (for example, some people only check the questions tagged as C++, and they haven't seen it yet). So please [edit] your question again. And by the way, showing what you have so far (for example, the code that works for a single matrix) would help.